# How can I concatenate string literals following Google C++ Style Guide?

Tags: c++

[Guide says](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Static_and_Global_Variables) using `const std::string obj` as an object having static storage duration is a bad idea as we have non-trivial destructor (it's about static and global variables).
What's the best way to create string literals if I have `path` variable (namespace global) and need to make path resources variables in this manner `path + "nameOfFile"` (unnamed namespaces in cpp files)?

Comment: What is `path`?

Comment: @melpomene most likely `std::string`.

Comment: Use `const char *` for `path` and then `std::string file = std::string(path) + "nameOfFile";`

Comment: @melpomene path is string object now, but if I find a way to get concatenation concisely through char*, then I use pointers

Comment: C style would be `#define PATH "/whatever/"` and then `PATH "somefile"`.

Comment: @frogatto `/* bad: non-trivial destructor */ const std::string kFoo = "foo";`. I use it in unnamed namespaces, and these objects have static storage duration, and Google Guide doesn't like your solution:)

Comment: @AlexanderMordovskiy I assume `std::string file` is a local variable not global or static one.

Comment: @frogatto made problem description more accurate

Comment: @melpomene but `#define` directive is bad practice in cpp code, isn't it?)

Comment: The Google C++ Style Guide is infamous for being anti-C++.  I strongly recommended that you stay away from it unless you are forced otherwise.

Comment: @L.F. I could reformulate the question without mentioning their guide, but the problem with objects with static storage duration will not go away. I also read reviews about their rules and did not find anything wrong. Everywhere you need to keep in mind the context:) Anyway thanks for the caution.

Comment: @AlexanderMordovskiy "using const std::string obj as an object having static storage duration is a bad idea as we have non-trivial destructor (it's about static and global variables)."  That's nonsense.  Having a non-trivial destructor is by no means problematic at all.

Comment: @L.F.: It seems to me that Google is hoping to prevent using anything [outside its lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) by giving everything a trivial destructor, but that rule is slated to [go away](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.4) in C++20.

Comment: @DavisHerring Well, then they can just prohibit non-trivial destructors altogether because there is the possibility of a dangling reference even if you use it as a local variable :(

Comment: @L.F.: That wouldn’t help if the *storage* had been lost for the local.  To be fair, it is really easy to have one global destructor reference another global object out of lifetime (from the usual ordering subtleties)—but that’s an argument for careful use (or avoidance) of static storage duration more than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical solution is to use `std::string_view`:

```
constexpr std::string_view path{"foo"};
```

Then you can use things like `path + "bar"`.

As a bonus, the destructor of `std::string_view` is trivial in both [libstdc++ (GCC)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sXGQEn4nNE9IW7KK) and [libc++ (Clang)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xwlCs8mqVwEC8Y7l)!  That's because a `std::string_view` is only just a `(ptr, count)`.  This isn't specified, but should be enough for circumventing a not-so-logical requirement in Google Style Guide.

Comment: @AlexanderMordovskiy You can also use the one from GSL.